# Using VMWare Workstation, to convert a physical Win2008 into a templtae

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm new to VMware and despite having read the documentations, I'm having trouble.

I'm using VMware workstation Stand-Alone package to turn a physical Win Server 2008 R2 into a usable VM appliance.

The source and destination part is getting me here.

It seems using keyword "localhost" doesn't cut all the way through.
Does the shared folder have to be in my local drive for that matter?

For ip, am I using the simple private IP that my nearest DHCP has given me? But what if I have more than one interfaces that have two or three different private ip addresses?

Thanks.

Comment: I am really confused about what you are trying to do.  Are you running Vmware Workstation on the machine that you are trying to turn into a virtual machine?  If yes, then you are doing things wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do. Please correct the part I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @SndLt: You're trying to nest a thing inside itself. It doesn't logically add up.

Comment: What is the "VMware workstation Stand-Alone package"? Do you mean the VMware vCenter Converter Standalone?

Comment: You want the [VMware converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/). It runs on another machine and does P2V.

Comment: "VMware vCenter Converter Standalone" yes, I shortened it. haha.  I'm having trouble with the different folder location things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your answer to my question here's what you can do:

1. Launch the VMware vCenter Converter Standalone application
2. Click the "Convert Machine" toolbar button
3. Select "Powered-on Machine" and "This local machine" options and click the Next button
4. Select "VMware Workstation or other VMware virtual machine" then select the appropriate VMware product. Type the name that you want this virtual machine to be named and select a folder for the converted machine to be created in (A USB drive or network share is probably preferred).
5. Edit any options as needed or desired and click the Next button.
6. Voila! If the task successfully completes then you'll have converted the physical machine to a virtual machine for the selected platform.

Comment: I used "\\HostName\\FolderName" as the destination  approach and it worked!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.